# User.Identity.GetUserId() and RequestContext.Principal.Identity.GetUserId() returns NULL in WEB API controller. Used Token based Aunthentication

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, http-token-authentication

I have used Tokens to secure my Web API website, and consumed this API from an AngularJS client application.

With this I am able to login with token based authentication.  My issue is that I am not able to get the `UserId` in Web API controller.

Both `User.Identity.GetUserId()` and `RequestContext.Principal.Identity.GetUserId()` are returning `null`.

How to get the `UserId` in an `ApiController`?

Comment: What framework are you using?  ASP.NET Identity?

Comment: Yes. Identity 2.0 , MVC 5. WEB API

Comment: User.Identity.GetUserId() should return the current logged in user's UserID. Are you trying with a logged in user (passing Bearer AuthToken) in the Authorization header while calling WebAPI?

Comment: Resolved .. There was a problem in passing AuthToken as a header. Now it is working fine.. Thanks ....

Comment: @RohitV please explain little or share code snippets how you resolve your issue i'm getting same issue Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a bearer token, set the Authorization header in javascript.

```
var token = sessionStorage.getItem(tokenKey);
var headers = {};
if (token) {
    headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token;
}
```

Then you should include headers in your ajax request:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'api/values/1',
        headers: headers
    }).done(function (data) {
        self.result(data);
    }).fail(showError);
```

Finally in your controller you can get user id by:

```
var userId = RequestContext.Principal.Identity.GetUserId();
```

for more information refer to [Secure a Web API with Individual Accounts and Local Login in ASP.NET Web API 2.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api)